# Problems using diff in bash to create and check hashes for an Apache2 service

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I keep reciving an syntax error using diff in bash. Here is the script. the part in Bold is where im having issues.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="/var/www/html/*";
varPath="/var/log/wwwHash";
tmpPath="/tmp/wwwHash";


if [[ -f $varPath ]];
        then mv $varPath $tmpPath;
fi

touch $varPath;


for f in $FILES ;
        do if [[ ! -d $f ]];
                then md5sum -t $f >> /var/log/wwwHash;
        fi ;
done;


if [[ `diff $varPath $tmpPath | wc -c` -lt 2 ]];
then echo "The files in the WWW/html folder have not changed";
else
        echo "The files in the WWW/html folder have changed."
        echo "The following are the files that have changed:"
        # Output which file has changed
        diff $varPath $tmpPath;
fi
```

With this part in particular causing the syntax error.

```
if [[ `diff $varPath $tmpPath | wc -c` -lt 2 ]];
then echo "The files in the WWW/html folder have not changed";
else
        echo "The files in the WWW/html folder have changed."
        echo "The following are the files that have changed:"
        # Output which file has changed
        diff $varPath $tmpPath;
fi
```

Comment: see if https://shellcheck.net can help. Good luck.

Comment: You can change your diff logic to "if [ -n "$(diff "${varPath}" "${tmpPath}")" ]; then ....